# Dynamic script with external src loading

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I have issues while loading some ad scripts. If the external server is not responding, the whole page waits for the respond and stops loading. How can I tell those problem scripts to start executing after:

1. The whole page is loaded.
2. All other scripts are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `defer` doesn't guarantee that it will defer both loading and running. You can control exact time when you want this script to start loading and executing by adding it to page dynamically by placing `<script>` with following contents after everything else you want to load and run:

```
var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
var script=document.createElement('script')
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
script.setAttribute('src', "http://your-script.com/address-here.js")
head.appendChild(script)
```

Comment: When does it happen that `defer` doesn't defer?

Comment: That looks like a solution. One more thing: how to set the script's content this way?
Example:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://externalsite.com/script.js">var ad_id = '123abc';</script>

Comment: Well, you always can `.createTextNode` and `script.appendChild` but even without looking in specs, I'm under impression that text child of script tag is silently ignored if you specify a `src` attribute.

Comment: @Kos, directly from Sam's answer link: "The defer attribute gives a **hint** to the browser that the script **does not create any content**". Which is already seems like not exactly good thing. And then later: "In our tests IE4+ deferred the execution of deferred scripts, **not their loading**."

Comment: Also, I've quickly refreshed myself on state of defer support in different browsers and it seems that so far not all of them exactly agree what (loading/run) is deferred, for how long and if it is guaranteed at all or not. So, manual control really seems to be better solution.

Comment: Sorry, wrong example. The right one is
<script type="text/javascript">var ad_id = '123abc';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalsite.com/script.js"></script>

But i got your point. I'll go give it a try

Comment: This is really the same as the above, so answer's the same.

Comment: I've tried this script

<script type="text/javascript">
var global_top_banner=document.getElementById('global_top_banner');
var global_top_banner_script_1=document.createElement('script');
var global_top_banner_script_2=document.createElement('script');

global_top_banner_script_1_content = document.createTextNode('ad_id = "9111698c-a0a7-4c49-843d-2489c193a862";');

Comment: global_top_banner_script_1.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
global_top_banner_script_1.appendChild(global_top_banner_script_1_content);

global_top_banner_script_2.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
global_top_banner_script_2.setAttribute('src', "externalsite.com/script.js");
global_top_banner.appendChild(global_top_banner_script_1);
global_top_banner.appendChild(global_top_banner_script_2);
</script>

It does writes itself in the correct div, but is not executed

Comment: Why do you need global_top_banner_script_1 at all when you're already in JS and can do `ad_id = "9111698c-a0a7-4c49-843d-2489c193a862"` yourself?

Comment: OK.

<script type="text/javascript">
var global_top_banner=document.getElementById('global_top_banner');
var global_top_banner_script=document.createElement('script');

ad_id = "9111698c-a0a7-4c49-843d-2489c193a862";

global_top_banner_script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
global_top_banner_script.setAttribute('src', "externalsite.com/script.js");

global_top_banner.appendChild(global_top_banner_script);
</script>

Still does write itself but doesn't execute

Comment: I've just tested this with a simple alert locally and it worked as expected. I can't help you with debugging further unless you upload your production code to somewhere public.

Comment: It gets called correctly, but render() inside invocationscript.aspx uses `document.write` to write results of its work inside document, which interacts badly with dynamic loading. You should consult you ad network documentation or support if they have alternate tag that would write inside specific container element on page instead of using document.write.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov are you really interested in how it works in IE 4+ or Firebird 0.x? I asked about the current age :).

Answer (score 1):

Use the DEFER attribute of javascript declaration:

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to defer your script. This will allow this rest of the page to load whilst this script is downloading.

Here is how to do it:

```
<script src="yourscript.js" defer="defer" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

More reading - http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/